# Import sql data with 00/00/0000 date

Tags: psql

I'm working with a column called 'track_endDate'. There are dates that are valid and then there are dates of 00/00/0000. Which I assume means the company is still working. I can't export this data into excel because I get an error of "invalid time, date, or time stamp. I've researched this a lot but I can't find any help. I'm using PSQL. Please help. SOS.

Comment: Why not convert those values to null?

Comment: How can I do this? I've tried 
SELECT 
 Track_endDate
 case when track_enddate is null then ' ' else 'nothing' end as 
        Track_enddate
FROM
      AddrStat